# Vite-Vue3 renderring dynamic images in a v-for

Tags: vuejs3, vite

I understand that i have to import images or use `new URL(...)` in order to render dynamic urls using Vite.

My problem is that the url I want to render is build in a v-for loop based on an object from a store (pinia) and I have not seen in the doc how to render such thing.

Here is the template of may component :
[Template of my component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjCVv.png)

So how to modify the "**img-src**" in the "**q-carousel-slide**" tag.

Thks for your help

@Daniel : The V-for create a simple card for each object with an image and a button :
[cardView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGSKr.png)

Comment: are the image urls pointing to static resources (ie /public or hosted elswhere) or are they being bundled?

Comment: All images are under /public/images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you **move the `images` directory into the `/public` folder** you can just use the dynamic string, just need to prepend the location (which you already have) and don't need to import anything.

Comment: They already are under /public/images/

Comment: if you have the images already there and are using what's in the image you included,, there should be no additional changes needed. What is the browser showing as the rendered url ?

Comment: I have put the image in the question

Comment: I mean, can you show what the DOM is showing the `src` is?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you want (sorry for that i'm a newbee and surely not a professinal!)

Comment: If you open up your browser debug tools `ctrl`+`shift`+`C`, and select an image tag, what does the source code say?

Comment: of course, i haven't think of this! it has to be a reflex. I can't make it today, i will do it tomorrow to answer you. thks again for interesting to my problem.

Comment: Thks a lot to guide me to find my mistake. It was a problem of bad url. In my `vite.config.js`  base was describe as `/tbm/`, and in the code, as you have seen, I forgot to add `/tbm/`. It works fine now, so thks again.